# Unable to use getListView()

Tags: android

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    setContentView(R.layout.history);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    readHistory();
    System.out.println("After history");
    //listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , tokens));
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.firstlist,R.id.title, data);
    System.out.println("AfterCA");
    //ListView.

    /*getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);*/}
```

I am getting errors at getListView()  Please Help  me for the same.

Comment: Plese be more specific. What errors are you getting?

Comment: you have to extend your class with ListActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `getListView()` you need to extend `ListActivity`. And second, you already have your listView with R.id.listView1, just use that!

Answer (score 2):

`getListView()` will be availabe only on class which is extending [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) So, you've to use your class by extending [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) like below -

```
public class myProject extends ListActivity
{
    // your stuff
}
```

A perfect example for [getListView()](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) with extending [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)